# matplotlib.pyplot and wx importing problems using python 2.7.10

Tags: python, matplotlib, wxpython, wxwidgets

I have installed many libraries for a project, but two specific libraries are giving me trouble when trying to import to python. These two are matplotlib.pyplot and wxpython. I have already followed many tutorial to see how to properly install these packages into python but so far I have had no luck. Here is the error that get when trying to import:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/AhmedNiri/Ahmed/2D_Mapping_Program_V7.py", line 13, in <module>
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-1.3.1-py2.7-macosx-10.9-x86_64.egg/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 98, in <module>
    _backend_mod, new_figure_manager, draw_if_interactive, _show = pylab_setup()
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-1.3.1-py2.7-macosx-10.9-x86_64.egg/matplotlib/backends/__init__.py", line 28, in pylab_setup
    globals(),locals(),[backend_name],0)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-1.3.1-py2.7-macosx-10.9-x86_64.egg/matplotlib/backends/backend_wxagg.py", line 6, in <module>
    import backend_wx    # already uses wxversion.ensureMinimal('2.8')
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-1.3.1-py2.7-macosx-10.9-x86_64.egg/matplotlib/backends/backend_wx.py", line 53, in <module>
    raise ImportError(missingwxversion)
ImportError: Matplotlib backend_wx and backend_wxagg require wxversion, which was not found.
```

So how do I know that these two libraries have been installed properly and in the desired directory?
I know that this might be an easy question to answer but I have been trying for a while to solve this and I also haven't had too much experience with python. Thanks in advance.

Comment: open python and type `import wxversion` ... if its not there you should re-install wxPython using apt-get (try following these directions http://wiki.wxpython.org/InstallingOnUbuntuOrDebian)

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that I am using a Mac OS and I've already used import wxversion and downloaded wxpython again but no luck @JoranBeasley

Comment: so you can `import wxversion` in a normal python shell? this implies you have multiple python interpretters (maybe 2.7 and 3.4) and whatever you are using to run your script is using the python that you do not have wx installed in ... Im guessing your wx is installed on one interpretter and your matplotlib is using a different interpretter.

Comment: @JoranBeasley no can't import anything, sorry for being unclear.

Comment: you cant import anything? or just cant import wxversion? can you import wx?

Comment: can't import wx and wxversion

Comment: what happens when you try `import wx`?

Comment: import wx

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    import wx
ImportError: No module named wx

Comment: doesn't even acknowledge it's existence and it doesn't even tell me if it needs any updating

Comment: that tells me that its not installed(for the interpretter you are in) .... try runing `locate wx.py` to find where it installed to when you installed it for mac

Comment: @JoranBeasley I looked into the directory where I installed wxpython I found wxversion in this directory and ran it. Then I try to find wx.py in the same place or in the whole mac but it doesn't even exist.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83795/discussion-between-joran-beasley-and-ahmed-niri).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was solved and the solution was as follow. After I installed wxpython and captured the output using "brew install wxpython> install.log 2>error.log", I figured out that when the wxpython is installed it does not have the proper directory and it also tells you exactly how to change this directory. The captured output looked like follow:

```
==> Installing wxpython dependency: wxmac
==> Downloading https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/wxmac-3.0.2.yosemite.bottle.10.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/wxmac-3.0.2.yosemite.bottle.10.tar.gz
==> Pouring wxmac-3.0.2.yosemite.bottle.10.tar.gz
  /usr/local/Cellar/wxmac/3.0.2: 777 files, 41M
==> Installing wxpython
==> Downloading https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/wxpython-3.0.2.0.yosemite.bottle.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/wxpython-3.0.2.0.yosemite.bottle.tar.gz
==> Pouring wxpython-3.0.2.0.yosemite.bottle.tar.gz
    ==> Caveats

Python modules have been installed and Homebrew's site-packages is not
in your Python sys.path, so you will not be able to import the modules
this formula installed. If you plan to develop with these modules,
please run:
  mkdir -p /Users/AhmedNiri/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages
  echo 'import site; site.addsitedir("/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages")' >> /Users/AhmedNiri/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/homebrew.pth
==> Summary
  /usr/local/Cellar/wxpython/3.0.2.0: 944 files, 38M
```

So if you look at the above execution you can see:

```
   Python modules have been installed and Homebrew's site-packages is not
    in your Python sys.path, so you will not be able to import the modules
    this formula installed. If you plan to develop with these modules,
    please run:
      mkdir -p /Users/AhmedNiri/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages
      echo 'import site; site.addsitedir("/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages")' >> /Users/AhmedNiri/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/homebrew.pth
```

This was the part that was used to solve the problem. I hope that this can help someone else and I would like to thank @JoranBeasley for his help.

Comment: Great answer! I was completely stuck and this solved my issue.